# Using distinct on a slice stringbuilder

Tags: scala, stringbuilder

```
buffer.slice(mouse,highlight).distinct
```

Now when I perform this it seems to apply `.distinct` to the whole string rather than the selection I use with `slice`. (`mouse` and `highlight` are just index positions and `buffer` is a `StringBuilder`). I'm just wondering what is the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. Please see below code for more clarification.
slice() function gives you the sub-string so in your approach It will first find the sub-string and then distinct.

Please follow below step by step approach for more understanding.

```
val buffer=new StringBuilder
buffer.append("bbbaabbbcccbdbcdbd")
val sl=buffer.slice(2,10)
```

The variable sl contains

```
sl= baabbbcc
```

Now you can apply distinct on sl variable

```
val result=sl.distinct
```

Finally your output

```
result= bac
```

This is the how your single line of code is working.

Comment: I hope this will help you!